# Azure API management - internal and accessible only by Azure application gateway?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-application-gateway

I have deployed the applications on Azure kubernetes that uses internal load balancer. API management is used in front of the load balancer to support authentication and caching & etc.

In order to protect the resources, I want to configure the API management  accessible only by the Azure application gateway.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by this "the Azure gateway"?

Comment: Azure app gateway

Comment: Did you check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-integrate-internal-vnet-appgateway?

Comment: @KaiWalter's link provides exactly the right guidance

Comment: If the link provided by Kai Walter helps your problem, could you please post an answer below ?